# Why does block quotes on a page not have the same quotation style?

Tags: html, css

I have several blockquote on a page. I notice that the first one has double quote " ; however the all the rest has single quote. I am not certain why.

The code I am using are

```
<blockquote>
<p>Dynamically network highly efficient testing procedures for tactical solutions. Seamlessly.</p>
</blockquote>
<blockquote>
<p>Dynamically network highly efficient testing procedures for tactical solutions. Seamlessly..</p>
</blockquote>
<blockquote>
<p>Dynamically network highly efficient testing procedures for tactical solutions. Seamlessly..</p>
</blockquote>
```

And the css is as follows

```
  blockquote {
    border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 6px;
    line-height: 140%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px;
  }
  blockquote:before{content:open-quote;font-size:4em;line-height:.1em;margin-right:.25em;vertical-align:-.4em;}
  blockquote :first-child{display:inline;}
  blockquote :last-child{margin-bottom:0;}
```

One can find it happening on a jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/u6gj18ev/

I am curious why it is happening and how to fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double quotes are for first quotes and single quotes are for inner quotes.

Because you only use `open-quote`, quotes don't get closed and the `quoteblock` after the first one, gets treated as inner quotes with single quotes.

You need to close the quotes with:

```css
blockquote:after {
    content: close-quote;
}
```

If you dont want closing quotes, you need to use:

```css
blockquote:after {
    content: no-close-quote;
}
```

If you want single quotes instead of double use:

```css
blockquote {
    quotes: "'" "'";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below,

It **Depends on user agent**, and if your checking on chrome, actually doesn't support `content:open-quote`

```css
  blockquote {
      background: #f9f9f9;
      border-left: 10px solid #ccc;
      margin: 1.5em 10px;
      padding: 0.5em 10px;
      quotes:"\201C""\201D""\2018""\2019";
  }
  blockquote:before {
      color: #ccc;
      content: "\"";
      font-size: 4em;
      line-height: 0.1em;
      margin-right: 0.25em;
      vertical-align: -0.4em;
  }
  blockquote p {
      display: inline;
  }
```

```html
<blockquote>
    <p>Dynamically network highly efficient testing procedures for tactical solutions. Seamlessly.</p>
</blockquote>
<blockquote>
    <p>Dynamically network highly efficient testing procedures for tactical solutions. Seamlessly..</p>
</blockquote>
<blockquote>
    <p>Dynamically network highly efficient testing procedures for tactical solutions. Seamlessly..</p>
</blockquote>
<blockquote>
    <p>Dynamically network highly efficient testing procedures for tactical solutions. Seamlessly..</p>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: Chrome supports `content:open-quote`. It's CSS2.1, so even IE8 supports it.

Comment: @Oriol no it doesn't..check your code in chrome and see

Comment: I am on Chrome and `content: open-quote;` does show quotes.

Comment: @gre_gor When you **open-quote** it will actually get closed automatically.But it depends on the **user-agent**..So the chrome doesn't support the automatic closing if you just use `content: open-quote;` only.